# tooltip on hidden "select" element doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, combobox, tooltip

I develop website using combobox from jquery UI, all work fine. But when I tried to apply tooltip on "select" element, tooltip doesn't work.

html:

```
<select id="combobox_courses" title="tooltip test text" style="display: none;">
```

All problem is cs jquery combobox override "select" css style display on "hidden" and change it with smth like that:
`<span class="ui-combobox"> <input class="ui-state-default ui-autocomplete-input ....`

I tried to use a lot of tooltip plugins and no one could fix this problem.
Usually all tooltip plugins have syntax like:

```
$("selector").anytooltip({settings});
```

Using class selector like .ui-combobox don't work too.

Any ideas how to fix this problem?
Sorry I'm beginner in Jquery and may be question is simple, thank you for your help...

**SOLVED!**

so if someone have this problem -
js:

> $(document).ready(function(){
>
> ```
> $('#wrapper').tipsy({ trigger: 'manual', gravity: 'n'});
>
> $( "#combobox" ).combobox();
> $("#wrapper input").bind("click", function() {
>       $("#wrapper").tipsy('show');
> }).bind("focusout",function(){
>       $("#wrapper").tipsy('hide');
> }); });
> ```

where #wrapper is wrapper of original combobox select element:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <div id="wrapper" title="test wrapper">
    <label>Your preferred programming language: </label>
    <select id="combobox">
        <option value="">Select one...</option>
    </select>
</div></div>
```

if  $("#wrapper input").bind(...); doesnt work just add span - $("#wrapper span input").bind(...);

*tipsy* is free tooltip plugin for jquery

*many thanks to @tpaksu for help!*

Comment: You are trying to display a tooltip of a hidden element??

Comment: Yes actually. The task is to show tooltip on select element of jquery combobox. The Evil is that jquery UI autocomplete ovveride original select element with own code(span, input etc.) and actually hide initial element :( you could see it here - http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/combobox.html

Comment: Have you tried adding the tooltip to the containing element (e.g. `P`, `DIV`) instead of the `SELECT`, itself?

Comment: As advised Tpaksu below I do, but it seems to me not flexible and rough solution... but better than nothing:)

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="combobox_courses" title="tooltip test text" style="display: block;">
```

or try to get a span and who wrap your select and get the tooltip on him

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this wouldnt work, cs jquery combobox plugin override original html - and "display" property should be "none" for this plugin normal work, check it out on http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/combobox.html

Comment: I wrote that span and wrap didn't work as wel... I couldn't bind tooltip on this selectors, its simply doesnt work:(

Answer (score 0):

You could add some wrapper element with a title and append the `ui-combobox` to this wrapper.

```
$('element').combobox({
  appendTo: 'elementWithTitle'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap this element with another container and set the tooltip to that element like this:

```
<div id="combo_container">
    <select id="combobox_courses" title="tooltip test text" style="display: none;">
</div>
```

Then you can define the tooltip to that container element:

```
$("#combo_container").anytootip({options});
```

Comment: Thank you, this is working. But lil bit rough solution... cs for example I have 2 autocomplete select boxes with input, and have to bind "focusout" event on first one to show tooltip on second one, when focus come to second, with "false" combobox containers I couldn't do this right?

Comment: you can use combobox events like `$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
   open: function(event, ui) { ... }
});` to trigger the tooltip focus.

Comment: Great idea, this could work :). In other case I guess I should rewrite combobox/autocomplete  script to fix this on more flexible way?

Comment: you can do mostly with events I think. modifying stable code could break something else that you can't see.

Comment: tried to bind some events as yous said, but with no success, could you give me example? Tried - 
`$(document).ready(function(){

$( "#municipality_cb" ).combobox({

                focus: function(event, ui) {

    //tipTip(); - tooltip script// 

  $("#municipality_wrap").tipTip({maxWidth: "auto", edgeOffset: 10}); 
                }

                });
});
`
what I do wrong?

Comment: you are re-creating the tooltip I guess. There should be a method to trigger the show event of the tooltip. don't reinstantiate the tooltip. show the existent one.

Comment: try changing the event to "open" instead of "focus".

Comment: tried, could you take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/wNnTQ/138/ ? anyway dont work :((